# How to change the height of an accordion in react?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I created an accordion using the [prime react UI library.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVlk7.png)

I just wan't to change the height of the accordion so it takes up more of the page. The accordion responds to changing the width in the style tag, **but doesn't respond to the height.** My question is how do you change the height?

```
export class ThirdPageAccordions extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div align="left" className="content-section implementation">
                <center>
                <Accordion style={{height: "50px", width: "100px"}} >
                    <AccordionTab header=" Data"  >
                    <DataTableinAccordion />
                    </AccordionTab>
                    <AccordionTab header=" Details">
                        <p></p>
                    </AccordionTab>
                    <AccordionTab header="Details II">
                        <p>Details II</p>
                    </AccordionTab>
                    <AccordionTab header="Cars">
                        <p> Cars </p>
                    </AccordionTab>
                    <AccordionTab header=" Summary">
                        <p> summary </p>
                    </AccordionTab>
                    </center>
                    </div>
                    );
                 }
             }
```

**EDIT: Whats circled in red is what I'm attempting to make larger**

[image: Whats circled in red is what I'm attempting to make larger]

*That extra space between the data header and the cars header was the result of changing the height via headerstyle{{height: "300px"}}*

**EDIT 2:** I added it here:

```
<Accordion  >
    <AccordionTab headerStyle={{height: "50px", }} header="DATA" >
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `style`, you should use `contentStyle` as it's says in the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/accordion) in `Properties For AccordionTab`. You should be changing the `AccordionTab`'s style.

```
<AccordionTab headerstyle={{height: "50px", width: "100px"}} >
    ...
</AccordionTab>
```

You can also change the header style with `headerStyle`.

If you want to pass a `className` you should use `contentClassName` and `headerClassName`.

Comment: Just gave this a shot, height remained the same

Comment: yeah I tried using higher px counts, and percentages height didn't budge

Comment: @JavaHava Just find the solution, that a look at my edit

Comment: ahhh  this makes more sense now that your clarified. I added this line of code: headerStyle={{height: "500px"}} in a tab header and the height changed except it just increased the whitespace between the accordions not the height of the headers. I'm posting what this looks like in my post

Comment: @JavaHava please be more clear on what's height you want to change. You are passing the style to `Accordion` but you aren't being clear on what you want to change.

Comment: Just edited my post above hope this helps, I'm trying to change the size of the header container of the accordion tabs

Comment: @JavaHava Where did you added `headerstyle`? Take a look ate my edit, you should add it yo `AccordionTab`, not `Accordion`

Comment: Yep I added it to accordion tab I'll post where I added it above