# Controlling the height inside a section for nested accordion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created an accordion component, when i am trying to use a nested level i am getting scroll  inside the accordion. I don't want to have a scroll inside the accordion inside the section instead of that the page should scroll below.

How could i achieve this.

**App.js**

```
import Accordion from "./Accordion";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion title="Whats lorem ipsum?">
        <Accordion title="Whats lorem ipsum?">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s.
        </Accordion>
        <Accordion title="Whats lorem ipsum?">
          <ul>
            <li>
              a) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.{" "}
            </li>
            <li>
              b) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.{" "}
            </li>
            <li>
              c) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.{" "}
            </li>
            <li>
              d) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.{" "}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </Accordion>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion title="Whats lorem ipsum?">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s.
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion title="Whats lorem ipsum?">
        <ul>
          <li>
            a) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.{" "}
          </li>
          <li>
            b) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.{" "}
          </li>
          <li>
            c) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.{" "}
          </li>
          <li>
            d) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.{" "}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have added the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hawking-x7tiw)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Refer this you may get  a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837059/how-to-change-the-height-of-an-accordion-in-react

Comment: But the mentioned one iss using prime react library

Comment: Check out the [document of accordion](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/accordion)

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots I got confused, i am not using prime react library, i have referred one and created the accordion, but when i use nested leve because of the children height its having scroll inside parent accordion thats where i am stuck

Comment: Oh ok i missed it ill check for any

Comment: You can see the codesandbox first accordion, its a nested one you could see a scroll, if i put maxHeight: none it will work but the smooth transition won't happen thats where i need help

Comment: Set useState -> setHeight as auto its 0 now

Answer (score 0):

According to your code in codesandbox inside

> Accordian/index.js

few changes workedout fine check it out.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Chevron from "./Chevron";

import "./style.css";

function Accordion(props) {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
  const [setRotate, setRotateState] = useState("accordion__icon");
  const [setMargin, setMarginState] = useState("0px");

  const content = useRef(null);

  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "0px" : "500px" // set pixel according to your needs 
    );
    setRotateState(
      setActive === "active" ? "accordion__icon" : "accordion__icon rotate"
    );
    setMarginState(setActive === "active" ? "0px" : "1rem");
  }

  return (
    <div className="accordion__section">
      <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
        <p className="accordion__title">{props.title}</p>
        <Chevron className={`${setRotate}`} width={10} fill={"#777"} />
      </button>
      <div
        ref={content}
        style={{
          maxHeight: `${setHeight}`,
          marginBottom: `${setMargin}`,
          overflow: "hidden" // set overflow as hidden
        }}
        className="accordion__content"
      >
        <div className="accordion__text">{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Accordion;
```

Comment: But all the accordions are getting opened by default when i apply the above changes

Comment: just a moment ill check it out

Comment: I have made some changes as on click the height is set to 500px based on your needs set it up in codesandbox seems to be fine. In your case parent and child are using same height of setHeight so once change it changes for both.

Comment: But the content is dynamic isn't so how could i decide a value for some accordions it will be 300 for some other 500? so thats why i used this ref isn't ?

Comment: Ya Ok anyway ill check for solution once i get any ,ill update you

Comment: for now can we remove this answer and update with proper so it will be  helpful for others

Comment: ya ok fine @ john